# Using selenium to fill in a form with random number

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am having trouble filling the form which using java creates a pair of random numbers and upon entering the right answer one can proceed:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<label for="captcha" class="..." id="captchaOperation">6 + 20 =</label>
```

I want to extract the two numbers, add them up (it is mainly the sum operation, but generic solutions are also appreciated).

I have used different combinations with `send_keys`, e.g.:

```
 mathcaptcha = action.send_keys("""document.querySelectorAll("span#captchaOperation").firstChild.nodeValue;""")
 print(mathcaptcha)
```

which all return:

```
<selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains object at 0x11238cd68>
```

Then I used the `execute_script` with few different scripts, e.g.:

```
mathcaptcha = driver.execute_script("""document.getElementById("captchaOperation");""")
print(mathcaptcha)
```

and got `None` printed out. 
How could I get the `6 + 20` out of the code or `26` as final result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `execute_script` return a value to you, use [return](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_return.asp) :

```
mathcaptha = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('captchaOperation').textContent;")
print(mathcaptha)
```

Comment: Thanks, I get {Message: unknown error: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null}

Comment: @mamad, sorry there was a typo. I fixed it, please try the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

mathcaptha = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "captchaOperation"))).text.replace(" =", "")
print(eval(mathcaptha))
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried with both Firefox and Chrome webdrivers, and got the following error:
Firefox: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="capthaOperation"]
Chrome:  Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"capthaOperation"}

Comment: I am getting a timeout exception with no message: {TimeoutException: Message: }

Comment: That's because there was a typo in your original code

Comment: well spotted @Andersson, but fixing the typo I still get `None`:
mathcaptcha = driver.execute_script("""document.getElementById("captchaOperation");""")

Comment: That's because you just execute  code without returning the value. `document.getElementById("captchaOperation");` simply define the WebElement, but do nothing with it

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to extract **6 + 20** you can use either of the following solution:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#other lines of code
captcha_text = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[@id='captchaOperation' and @for='captcha']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML")
print((captcha_text.replace("=", "")), eval(captcha_text.replace("=", "")))
```

Comment: @mamad I am fine with your edits as long as it caters to your question. Perhaps in your question you have asked **How could I get the `6 + 20` out of the code** but not to evaluate it :) Let me know if it answers your question.